# firebase.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack

I am using Webpack with firebase and firebase-admin.

To install firebase I ran:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

I am importing firebase using:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
```

I also tried:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

And I tried:

```
const firebase = require('firebase')
```

As suggested in [web get started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

However, when I try to use `firebase.auth()` I get an error:

> console.js:32 TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function

When I use the debugger to inspect `firebase` I see that it in fact does not have an `auth` function:

```
> firebase
 {__esModule: true, initializeApp: ƒ, app: ƒ, Promise: ƒ, …}
```

How can I get `auth()` included as a function using webpack?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of Firebase installed? They make upgrades daily, so I always check to make sure my version is the latest available. [Firebase Releases](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)

Comment: can you confirm you have successfully initialised the firebase app? are other bits working, like the database.

Comment: If you are not sure, I wrote a guide to setting up here https://joshpitzalis.svbtle.com/setup and an auth specific one here https://joshpitzalis.svbtle.com/auth . If you're still having trouble let us know.

Comment: I had the same problem too, i did yarn install and fixed the error.

Comment: CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

Typescript:
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

where the PACKAGE is the individual firebase service you want to use.

Comment: If you are looking at this in 2024, the problem is likely due to Firebase moving to a module architecture in Firebase version 9. See answer below from @Devlang Saklani https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413563/11809641

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting my `node_modules` directory and reinstalling everything.

Also I'm importing firebase like so:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
require('firebase/auth')
```

Comment: Work for me as well but I did not need to reinstall node_modules. Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me and seems to be an issue that occurs when you have both firebase and firebase-admin installed in the same package. Downgrading to firebase@v4.7.0 worked for me, with the issue appearing at firebase@v4.8.0. The issue is being discussed on the firebase repo here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752).

Comment: Can confirm @isTravis's information resolved my issue. I had BOTH firebase 5.4.1 with firebase-admin 6.0.0 in my package.json. `npm update firebase` upgraded me to 5.5.4 and the firebase.auth() is not a function problem started appearing. The firebase-admin package wasn't even being used in my app so I `npm uninstall firebase-admin` and everything started working once again.

Comment: I wonder if it is a version / package incompatibility problem (between `firebase` and `firebase-admin`). I reinstalled with `--save`, `package-lock.json` was updated, but now everything works.

Comment: Assuming you're on client, the best way I found that solves the problem is the following:

`import firebase from "firebase/app"; import "firebase/auth"; firebase.initializeApp({...}) export const auth = firebase.auth();`

Answer (score 46):

The problem wasn't with the `node_modules`, it was with the way that you were importing the component.

When you export a component ES6 way, you normally do `export default () => { console.log('default component export'); };`

`default` is the keyword here, when you import a component ES6 way like `import firebase from 'firebase'` it's grabbing the `default` property from the exported object.

Keeping in mind the above example, here's what you've done wrong.

Using ES6:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

console.log(firebase.auth) // Undefined
console.log(firebase.default.auth) // Function
```

Using ES5:

```
var firebase = require('firebase')

console.log(firebase.auth) // Undefined
console.log(firebase.default.auth) // Function
```

Note the `.default`

Comment: Did you test this?  When I run it I get valid entries for both auth and default.auth. My console:  https://snag.gy/fWIUCs.jpg and my code: https://snag.gy/hyAoum.jpg

Comment: Didn't work when I tried. Tried on node though, not on the browser

Comment: I see. I tried in the browser. I thought the issue may have been webpack related which is why I was using the browser

Comment: "always prefer the non cargo cult answer".  So if I understand: (a) re-installing packages is a red herring. (b) either `require ('firebase')` then `firebase.default.auth` OR `require(firebase/auth`)` then `firebase.auth`.  +1

Comment: @radarbob Seems to depend on the environment you're using. I tested Joao's answer and it did not work in my environment. I'm stuck with some crazy Babel Webpack Version 1 shenanigans. It was fixed for me by reinstalling the packages, and that answer has been upvoted several times so that means it probably worked for others as well. SO auto-awarded the bounty to this answer. In any case, it seems like Joao's response does help clarify some things about javascript imports in this new world, though it did not solve the issue I ran into.

Comment: This is the answer that fixed the issue for me. I was leaving out the `default` when calling the function

Answer (score 19):

I kept getting an error that said

> "TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function"

I got the auth object to appear and the thing I did differently was install the modules in a different order.

The first time I installed the modules (this is when the auth object wasn't appearing):

```
// this seems to confuse things with the auth object when installed in this order
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
$ npm install firebase --save
```

I deleted the npm folder and started from scratch although this time I reversed the installation order:

```
// for some reason this worked and now I can access the auth object
$ npm install firebase --save
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

I didn't do anything else. I simply reversed the installation order by installing firebase first and firebase-admin second.

I hope this works for other people.

[You can read more about it here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752#issuecomment-389508849)

Comment: I know it’s very strange. I had a headache with this for months, did a bunch of research, nothing worked. I just randomly decided to try it and it worked. It was literally a lucky guess. ‍♂️

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Details here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752#issuecomment-432003856

Comment: Note that `firebase-admin` (Which is just a firebase client with admin privileges) is not intended to be used in front-end apps like reactJS or VueJS but only in a secure server environment like stated in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user otherwise that would be a big security flaw. A solution would be using a cloud function and triggering it with an action the non-admin client could perform

Answer (score 14):

just add >

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
require('firebase/auth');
```

into your project

Comment: why require and not import?

Comment: You can use an import statement as well; 
```
import Firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Answer (score 11):

this is the import statement from official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup):

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import firebase from "firebase/app";
// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
console.log(firebase.auth);
```

<s>These also seem to work if you only want auth:</s>
Edit: The code below worked with Firebase 7 package but not any more with version 8. It will change again for Firebase 9. Just stick to the docs and you will be fine.

```
import { auth } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
console.log(auth);
```

or

```
import { auth } from "firebase";
console.log(auth);
```

Answer (score 11):

The main reason for this error could be due to the latest Firebase version v9.1.1, in this version the Firebase imports have been changed.

```
Before: version 8

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Check docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: This is the correct solution for the latest Firebase. For similar results using 'require':  
`const firebase = require("firebase/compat/app");
require("firebase/compat/auth");
require("firebase/compat/firestore");`

Answer (score 9):

Though there are many root causes behind this issue, a simple one like this also could be the case.

I forgot to include the js files for auth and db although I use them inside the JS code.

Before the fix;

```html
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

After the fix;

```html
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. While ``firebase-app.js needs to be the first to be included, the other SDKs (for auth, database, etc) as required must be added separately.

When using this in ES6 the specific SDK must either be imported or required separately.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to use the import as following

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
```

in the above case, both auth and DB services are being used.
For any other service, you need to import like that only.

Answer (score 8):

This is because firebase-auth script is not added.

First you have to install npm files in your node modules by

```
npm install firebase --save
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Then you have to add the script of firebase.auth after firebase-app script and **make sure the version is same.**

**Before fix:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

**AFTER FIX YOU NEED TO ADD BOTH THE SCRIPT AND AFTER THIS ADD YOUR FIREBASE ACCOUNT SCRIPT AS FOLLOWS**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

**THEN IT SHOULD WORK FINE**

Comment: yes. Oddly, in the getting-started docs for the authorization package, that `firebase-auth` script is not prominently mentioned. It appears in a link _back_ to setting up a firebase application, in the "Add Firebase SDKs" section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#add-sdks-initialize

Answer (score 6):

With firebase v9 you can not use auth like that anymore. Instead of that you need to import auth  from "firebase/auth"  like:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

and if you need to export auth object

```
const auth = getAuth();
export { auth };
```

if you need to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword  function

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
```

You can check the official documentation for more

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 3):

When running in Node and needing both `firebase` and `firebase-admin` this works for me:

First install `firebase` and then `firebase-admin` in that order.

Then use as so:

```
const app = require('@firebase/app');
require('@firebase/auth');
require('@firebase/firestore');

const firebase = app.firebase

firebase.initializeApp({…})

const auth = firebase.auth()
const db = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: Cannot find module '@firebase/app'
If I remove the @s I get error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

Answer (score 3):

Firebase 8 introduced some breaking changes.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020

Now you can make it work like this if you use **.default**:

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app').default
require('firebase/auth')

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const auth = firebase.auth()
```

Comment: I use 

`import { default as firebase } from 'firebase/app';`  in typescript

Comment: This gives me an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apps')

Answer (score 3):

In Firebase V9's JS SDK, thanks to Typescript, what I did is below:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

async login = (email: string, password: string) => {
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email, password)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. My issue was the npm module @firebase was installed as well as the firebase module. When I required firebase in my JavaScript code with ‘require(“firebase”)’, webpack bundled @firebase instead for some reason.

@firebase doesn’t include auth, database etc. by default...it’s modular so you can require them separately. Consequently I received the above error when I tried calling auth().

To fix it you can remove @firebase...or just add the full path to the correct firebase when you require it like

require(‘/path/to/node_modules/firebase/firebase.js’)

Comment: This answer seems quite confused. Of course `@firebase` is installed (which is not a module itself; it's a "scope", with modules such as `app` or `database` under that scope). that is where most of the logic for the various firebase modules is implemented. By the way, what do you mean by your suggestion to "remove" `@firebase`?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, I think it's because of versions troubles.
I solve it by deleting `node_modules` and all `webpack` generated stuff and take versions from [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/blob/master/auth-sessions/package.json).
Btw, I think it's very strange behavior, because it should work like in official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-app.js"> </script>
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-auth.js"> </script>
<script>
// Firebase settings of your web application
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "your apikey",
authDomain: "hackatonteleton.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://name-database.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "name-projectid",
storageBucket: "name.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "730018138942",
Application ID: "1: 730018138942: web: eb12fac2f91fb17f"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp (firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth ();
</script>
```

The difference you notice is that they need:

```
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-auth.js"> </script>
```

and initialize the function

```
const auth = firebase.auth ();`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. However I didn't have to do any deletion of any files, just correct the import statements. In my case I use Firebase version 7.7.0 in an Gatsby/React app and this is what the import looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.GATSBY_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    this.uiConfig = {
      signinOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ],
    };
  }
}
export default Firebase;

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
export { FirebaseContext };
```

Update after request from @Mel. The context may be used using either a HOC:

```
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

or using a hook:

```
import { FirebaseContext } from './firebase';
const MyComponent = () => {
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  // do something with firebase
};
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My config file looks like yours. Please can you show me how you managed to use in the context config. I stuck on this error and can't find a way through

Comment: @Mel I added examples how to use the context. However, in the end I switched to use `gatsby-plugin-firebase`, as it just works out of the box, one only have to add firebase settings. In that way I didn't have to invent the wheel again. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

This may solve the issue, try this >>>

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {  };

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  export { auth, provider };
```

most probably you forgot to put 'new' in this line --->

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

check again.

Answer (score 2):

//If you have firebase version 9 you can solve it just importing firebase in this way:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

//This works in my case. For more detail follow the documentation link above:

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

What-up. I ran into this while working through William Candillon's [Adding Firebase To React Native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TlOhmdl3-M&t=173s) tutorial...

Thoughts: There is a lot to love about Firebase. But the import/export, named vs default and versioning seems to bring a lot of people a lot of unnecessary heart-ache. <-- I say that with tears streaming down my face and a hole in my heart where a love of mobile development & unhappy childhood used to exist mere hours ago.

Put simply: I had `firebase.auth is not a function`.
Went hunting though node_modules, deleted, re-yarn'd, read blogs, tried importing as named then default, requiring separate modules a-la `require('firebase/auth');` under the default import of firebase itself etc etc etc (it really shouldn't be this hard). Also, why do Google not have react documentation? It's 2018. Are people seriously still putting HTML script tags in their front end?

Current Solution => in the end I pulled all my config and `firebase.initializeApp(config)` into my top level app.js. I'll have to find time later to figure out why the "@firebase" module of auth can't be imported. Or why thats even there? Do i need it? Why isn't it all wrapped into the 'yarn add firebase' module?

Anyway - that'd be my advice. Get it working at top level first. Then hive-off the credentials into a separate file later. That and "Dont drink lager. It bloats-you-out and IPA is infinitely nicer."

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything in this post, but nothing worked for me.

I discovered the issue with my imports and exports. This worked for me:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.firestore();

export { auth, database } 
import { auth, database} from '@/firebase.js';
```

This was my mistake:

```
export default { auth, database }
import auth from '@/firebase.js';
```

My first mistake: I did a export default with two values and this doesnt work. The second mistake, if you export with curly braces, you need to import with curly braces. Otherwise you will get a "Cannot read property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

**I used this import Statement & it solved the issue**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
var auth=require("firebase/auth")
console.log(auth)
```

You will get to access all  the methods of auth

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with error **firebase.auth** is not a function since after version-8 there is a change in auth function.

I am using firebase version **^9.6.11** and below is the fix.

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
export const loginRequest = (email, password) => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};
```

I hope this would help if anyone is facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

## My Solution: Completely Remove Node, NPM, NVM & Re-Install

This problem has happened to me a few times in the past (whenever I tried up update or install my node_modules). I literally tried everything above. It always seemed to randomly start working and I was unable to use any previously documented solution the next time the error occurred.

I think I may have had some carry-over issues since I started using Firebase in the early days when there were some weird hacks I did in **macOS** to get firebase to work correctly.

This solution basically completely removes any trace of node / npm / nvm from your Mac, and re-installs it to use the exact version of node that firebase runs. This uses **nvm** so if you have other projects that require different node versions, you can switch between node versions on the fly.

### 1. Delete Existing Node Modules

In your project's folder, delete any `node_modules` folders you have.

### 2. Remove Node

[This is the tutorial I used to manually remove node](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/). In the early days, I remember having to change something to install node into a different directory (due to permission issues), so I also did additional searches on my computer to remove these files and folders from other areas.

### 3. Remove NPM

[This is the tutorial I used to make sure I removed traces of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html)

### 4. Remove NVM

[This is the tutorial I used to manually remove NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/298)

## 5. Restart

After removing everything and restarting bash (or restarting your Mac as I did for safety) - typing `node`, `npm`, and `nvm` into the console should simply return `command not found`.

## 6. Re-Install Node, NPM Using NVM Only

NVM allows you to install a specific version of node. Since I am using the firebase-functions **node 8** runtime (beta), I installed their listed target version of node 8. (as of now, [node 8.11.1](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/cloud-functions-for-firebase-config-node-8-timeout-memory-region.html)). This is still in beta, firebase functions uses node 6.11.5 as of the time of this writing.

[Instructions for installing node, npm using nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

## 7. Update NPM Manually

NVM installed an older version of npm. This command updates NPM to its latest version.

`npm install npm@latest -g`

## 8. Install Your Modules

Restart your terminal app just in case, then return to your project folder and run the `npm install` command.

## 9. Re-Build & Re-Deploy

If you are using webpack, re-build your project. Then deploy or serve locally.

This process solved the problem for me. Hopefully it works for you and you don't have to do any hack stuff. It seems all I needed to do was some cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to delete my node_modules folder.
Just confirm if you've both '@firebase' and 'firebase' subfolders inside node_mudules.
If you do, change the path to 'firebase' on your require statement to
'./node_modules/firebase'

and make the next line;
require('./node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth');

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using version 9

Refer this [doc section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_up_new_users)

```
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
```

you should be using `getAuth`in order to get "auth" reference.

OR

try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413563/11016275) if you don't want to make code changes

Answer (score 0):

before firebase v9

```
  import 'firebase/auth'
```

in firebase v9

```
  import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
  export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your code does and how is answers the question? don't simply post a code.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version, you can make it work like this
Am using `firebase` version `"firebase": "^10.3.0",`

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const config = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG ?? "{}");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// @ts-ignore
const auth = getAuth();

export async function loginWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return {
      user,
      status: true,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      error: err as Error,
      status: false,
    };
  }
}
```