# How to resolve or troubleshoot firebase deployment issue?

Tags: firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am a beginner with Firebase. Facing an issue while deploying functions with Firebase. Could you please suggest how to resolve or troubleshoot the issue

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> TypeError: QH.jj is not a function
> at /home/circleci/xxx/functions/index.js:1328:601
> at /home/circleci/xxx/functions/index.js:6:22
> at Object. (/home/circleci/xxx/functions/index.js:10:3)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at loadModule (/home/circleci/xxx/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/runtimes/node/triggerParser.js:10:16)

The code line getting issue:

> var QH=require("aws4-axios");require("process");const RH=process.env.ej,SH=process.env.API_PATH,TH=QH.jj

Appreciate your help!

Comment: It seems that you have an error at line 1328 of your `index.js` file. Without your code and what is at this line, we cannot help you.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Here is the code in index.js
```
1324 create(undefined, 'import * as m from "' + this.path + '"; goog.Dependency.callback_("' + registerKey + '", m)');
1325   var afterKey = goog.Dependency.registerCallback_(function() {
1326    goog.Dependency.unregisterCallback_(afterKey);
1327     controller.clearModuleState();
1328      controller.loaded();
1329   });
1330    create(undefined, 'goog.Dependency.callback_("' + afterKey + '")');
```
Some time it showing error in 1330 line

Comment: Run npm install -g firebase-tools@latest and then try. please edit your question to provide the code sample

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Did not help. Adding code in the question

Comment: please check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) format your code.Also have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181445/typeerror-firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thanks @SathiAiswarya. I add the code line which I am getting issue now. Some issue with aws4-axios. Import statement was
import { aws4Interceptor } from 'aws4-axios';