# Express & Firebase - Failing to set header before redirect

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make Firebase authentication work on the server.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
//const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');
const app = express();

// Express middleware that validates Firebase ID Tokens passed in the Authorization HTTP header.
// The Firebase ID token needs to be passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header like this:
// `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
// when decoded successfully, the ID Token content will be added as `req.user`.

const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token');

   if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
  !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)) {
       console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.',
    'Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:',
    'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>',
    'or by passing a "__session" cookie.');
    res.redirect("/login");
    return;
   }

   let idToken;
   if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
   console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
     // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
     idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
   } else if(req.cookies) {
     console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
     // Read the ID Token from cookie.
     idToken = req.cookies.__session;
   } else {
     // No cookie
     res.redirect("/login");
     return;
   }

   admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
      console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
      req.user = decodedIdToken;
      return next();
   }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
      res.redirect("/login");
   });
 };

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("/public"));
app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser);
//app.use(expressSanitizer());
//app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);=
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// This HTTPS endpoint can only be accessed by your Firebase Users.
// Requests need to be authorized by providing an `Authorization` HTTP header
// with value `Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);



app.post("/login", (request, response) => {

   var idToken = request.body.token;

   console.log("REQUEST BODY = " + idToken);

   response.header("Authorization" , "Bearer " + idToken);

   return response.redirect("dashboard");
});

app.get("/dashboard", validateFirebaseIdToken, (request, response) => {
   response.redirect("/dashboard/new");
});
```

In the `/login` POST route, I am receiving the `idToken` as expected (and showed in the logs). **It seems though, that the response is unable to preserve/maintain the header property `Authentication: Bearer <Firebase ID token>`** set beforehand.

In fact, I sent a GET request in Postman to `/dashboard` by getting the idToken printed by the logs and setting it in the header of the request like `Authorization: Bearer <idToken>` and it worked perfectly.

[Here it says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235438/set-express-response-headers-before-redirect) that redirects are in fact new HTTPS requests and therefore don't preserve the header set in the response. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the Authorization header with **every** request.  HTTPS functions are stateless.  They don't remember anything from a prior request.  So, you shouldn't depend on redirect behavior to retain state.  Instead, the client needs to figure out where to go next and make the next request itself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I didn't understand much. Isn't express going to receive the idToken and verify it using the admin SDK? What should I do?

Comment: I get the point that I have to send the idToken from the client (which would be the best way to do the request from inside the `AuthStateChanged` callback?), but how do I ensure the Authorization header is in every request?

Comment: In my answer, I said that you should NOT depend on a redirect.  Find another way to get your work done without using a redirect, as it won't let you specify the header in the redirected request.

Comment: Any suggestions you would recommend?