# XMLHttpRequest does not reload page

Tags: javascript, firebase, xmlhttprequest, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log("Signed in");
    return user.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
        console.log("Token = " + idToken);
        var bearer = "Bearer " + idToken;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "dashboard");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", bearer);
        return xhr.send();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log("User signed out");
  }
});
```

I am doing the following request. In my server I am receiving logs saying it has received the request and it has recognized it as an authenticated user and so on. In  fact, to test, I sent it to a simple endpoint like `/hello` where I simply do `res.render("Hello World!")` in my express app but even then nothing happens on the page. Why isn't the browser refreshing the page to represent the response from the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't the browser refreshing the page to represent the response from the endpoint?

Because the **entire** point of Ajax is that the response is passed to JavaScript so you can do what you like with it instead of loading a whole new page.

You can access the data with:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
});
```

Comment: But I would like to load a new web page, i.e redirect the user to the `/dashboard` endpoint when he press the login button. I tried using form with `action="/dashboard" method="post"` but got no luck setting the authorization header on the server (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900309/express-firebase-failing-to-set-header-before-redirect/50900752)

Answer (score 0):

What you're now building is essentially a webapp which communicates with an API from JS. Since you're doing logic client-side instead of server-side now, instead of using Express to redirect to another route after login you have to do client-side routing.

This means after you've received a successful response (200) from the API you have to direct the client to the desired route. So you would do something like:

```
if (user) {
  window.location = "/dashboard";
}
```

However it seems like you're doing client-side logic by accident. Therefore I would recommend to stop using XMLHttpRequest and just use `<form>` as you were doing in your other post and continue your efforts to try to get that working. In that way you can continue building a server-rendered ExpressJS app.

Comment: Niels, do you have any idea how could I pass the authorization header before the redirect? And more specifically, since HTTP and the server (express) is stateless, how do I make sure every request from now on (after user login) has the authorization token in the header? Please take a look at this other post of mine as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643768/how-to-check-if-user-is-authenticated-in-firebase-and-express-node-js?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This is driving me crazy. There's not enough documentation on how to handle Firebase Authentication + Express

Comment: You could use sessions so when the client is logged in you save that fact in a cookie. [https://nodewebapps.com/2017/06/18/how-do-nodejs-sessions-work/](This is a good explanation) for using sessions in Express. Look at the part where he sets a property on `req.session`: you can add a boolean like `isLoggedIn` there.