# Firebase Authentication - SignIn issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I got **login form** - `SignIn.js`:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange} />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
</form>
...  
export default firebaseConnect()(SignIn);
```

and **onSubmit**, where I want to login to **Firebase/Firestore**

```
 onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { firebase } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase
      .login({email, password})
      .catch(err => alert('Invalid Login Credentials'));
  };
```

When I try to login i got this error:

```
TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
```

I have tried also this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

but I got the same issue.

My **store**:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer});
const initialState = {};    
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

const rrfProps = {
 firebase,
 config: {},
 dispatch: store.dispatch,
 createFirestoreInstance};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>

      <App />

    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**firebaseConfig**.js

```
const fc = {
//data from Firebase (apiKey, authDomain...)
}    
firebase.initializeApp(fc);
firebase.firestore();
export default firebase;
```

Comment: how have you added firebase to your project?

Comment: yes, I can read data from firebase

Comment: const app = firebase.initializeApp(appConfiguration);
const auth = app.auth();

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).... should work. 

I think you are referring wrong auth may be?

Comment: tried but did not help....if you have somewhere working example with **auth.signIn** please provide me some link

Comment: have you looked at :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592656/firebase-auth-is-not-a-function/

Comment: thank you @Thomson Tran for link, it's resolved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [firebase.auth is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592656/firebase-auth-is-not-a-function/) I did as follow inside my `firebaseConfig.js`

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

albo this is working as well:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
```