# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have done logging in and logging in to the application. I also use a realtime database and wanted the user transactions to be added to the database to be allocated to their account. Unfortunately, I got an error after adding firebaseDb.auth (). CurrentUser.uid.

Error:

TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_.default.auth is not a function

firebaseDb
-> .child("Expenses/" + firebaseDb.auth().currentUser.uid)
.on("value", (snapshot) => {

Code:

```
const ExpensesList = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");
  const [RelatedPersonsObjects, setRelatedPersonsObjects] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDb
      .child("Expenses/" + firebaseDb.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val() != null)
          setRelatedPersonsObjects({
            ...snapshot.val(),
          });
        else setRelatedPersonsObjects({});
      });
  }, []);

  const addOrEdit = (obj) => {
    if (currentId === "")
      firebaseDb.child("Expenses/ + firebaseDb.auth().currentUser.uid").push(obj, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId("");
      });
  };
```

firebase config

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/auth";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
};

var fireDb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export default fireDb.database().ref();
```

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48592656/2873538).

Answer (score 0):

Just put `require('firebase/auth')` below import firebase in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What is `firebaseDb`? If it is the default export from your firebase config (`fireDb.database().ref()`) that is not what you should be using. `fireDb.database().ref()` [returns a Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#ref). Instead, you should export `auth` from your firebase config (which it looks like you already have), import it into the file using ExpensesList and then simply use `auth.currentUser.uid`.

```
import { auth } from "../firebaseConfig" // Or whatever the path is

const ExpensesList = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");
  const [RelatedPersonsObjects, setRelatedPersonsObjects] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDb
      .child("Expenses/" + auth.currentUser.uid)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val() != null)
          setRelatedPersonsObjects({
            ...snapshot.val(),
          });
        else setRelatedPersonsObjects({});
      });
  }, []);

  const addOrEdit = (obj) => {
    if (currentId === "")
      firebaseDb.child("Expenses/ + auth.currentUser.uid").push(obj, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId("");
      });
  };
```