# firebase.auth/storage/database is not a function but firebase.storage is

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning node.js with firebase/firestore.  For some reason only firebase.firestore() is being recognized as a function.  firebase.auth(), firebase.storage() and firebase.database() are not being recognized as functions.

I'm using the basic code from one of the youtube examples:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

also this question appears to be in the same territory but was not helpful for me.
[Firebase Initializing Without Auth - firebase.auth is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551602/firebase-initializing-without-auth-firebase-auth-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you included all firebase plugin ? from the doc :

> You can reduce the amount of code your app uses by just including the
>   features you need. The individually installable components are:
>
> - firebase-app - The core firebase client (required).
> - firebase-auth - Firebase Authentication (optional).
> - firebase-database - The Firebase Realtime Database (optional).
> - firebase-storage - Firebase Storage (optional).

Comment: In the node_modules firebase folder I have all of the sub folders(storage/storage types, auth/auth types etc.).  Also I did nothing particular for setting up firestore.